# Function executing twice upon import in unitttest

Tags: python, function, import

For some reason the function all_files_df() is executing twice in the code below.  The len(data) should be 4, but it's returning 8.

I thought adding:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

at the bottom would fix that issue, but apparently I need to be doing something else.  See code below...

```
import unittest
from csv_file_testing import all_files_one_df


class TestCSVMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_df_length(self):
        data = all_files_one_df()
        self.assertEqual(4, len(data))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When running the all_files_one_df() by itself it runs fine and returns 4 rows

all_files_one_df() loops through a folder and concactenates the CSV files into one dataframe.  In this case each CSV file contains 2 rows of data.  2 files x 2 rows = 4 rows total

```
def all_files_one_df():
    for file in all_files:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0)
        li.append(df)

    frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    return frame
```

Comment: it will be hard to help u if you don't show us what  `all_files_one_df()` does

Comment: @LiorCohen thanks.  I added more details

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  The issue was with the file I was importing, not the unittest file itself.

I needed to change this at the bottom:

```
all_files_one_df()
```

To this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_files_one_df()
```

Now it seems obvious.  Importing the file before was executing it as well.  It needed that check in place to ensure it doesn't